# Two Foreign Keys in one Column. How to split?

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation.

Combinations Table:
`Combination ID | Option ID's`

Options Table: 
`Option ID | Option Name | Option Value` 

The "Option ID's" column in the combinations table reads like "2345,3421" (in the one column) when refering to the two options associated to the combination. 

Is it possible to generate a list that lists all possible combinations and values for each combination?

ie. `combination1 | option1 | name:size | value:Small | option2 | name:color | value:Blue`

Comment: Not in any kind of clean way.  You've violated First Normal Form, and the complication you're experiencing is the price of doing so.

Comment: it wasn't me :) this is from working with interspire shopping cart.

Comment: Fair enough.  It'll be interesting to see some suggestions, at any rate.  Sadly, this is probably going to involve lots and lots of ugly join predicates.  Things like this can be done, but it's never pretty.

Comment: great fun. variations seem to be one of the hardest parts of a shopping cart in my experience. i wonder if anyone has nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like this -

```
SELECT
  c.Combination_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(o.Option_Name, '=', o.Option_Value))
FROM
  combinations c
LEFT JOIN options o
  ON find_in_set(o.Option_ID, c.Option_IDs)
GROUP BY
  c.Combination_ID
```

Agree with Ian McLaird about the table normalization.

---

```
SELECT
  c.Combination_ID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.Option_Name),
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.Option_Value)
FROM
  combinations c
LEFT JOIN options o
  ON find_in_set(o.Option_ID, c.Option_IDs)
GROUP BY
  c.Combination_ID
```

Comment: one more question while you are busy being awesome. Can the returned o.option_name and values be split into seperate columns?